# How to inspect the UI for xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

During the xamarin forms development, how to verify if a control is occupying certain pixels in the screen.

(i.e) Like we verify for a web page by going through the developer tools of a browser of the styles each of the element occupies.

Is this possible with Xamarin emulator? To verify if the UI is coming up as expected on the emulator?

Comment: Runtime iOS View UI Hierarchy via Xcode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50568798/how-to-attach-xcode-view-debugger-to-the-simulator-launched-from-visual-studio/50572976#50572976

Comment: Runtime Android View UI Hierarchy via Android Studio / Layout Inspector https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Xamarin Inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/inspector/) if you can afford a Visual Studio Enterprise subscription.

If you can't afford this (about 6000 $ p.a. is quite something), you could use the Appium Inspector ([see here](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop)). It's very generic and hence not optimized for Xamarin Forms, but it might do the trick, if you're on a budget.

It allows you to inspect the UI elements and verify that they take the space they should. This is approximately how it looks (I think it's an older version):

[image: Appium Inspector]

Anyway, it's somewhat tricky to set up, but if you have set it up, you can use it to run UI-tests, too (that's what it's usually used for).

**Bonus:** The lowest key variant to verify that your controls take the space they should is simply setting their background color and visually inspect your layout.